# Why does Windows 10 report that a file was edited tomorrow?

Tags: windows-10

I have noticed that Windows 10 intermittently reports that a file was edited tomorrow when grouped by date modified. When the window is refreshed, it updates to today. Why is this? Is this a bug?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Did the files come from (say) an Australian server or sender, where the date was tomorrow already?

Comment: All files are being edited locally only.

Comment: OK. It was a long shot. No other ideas come to mind.

Comment: are those files from a network location / external storage device ?

Comment: Files are on C:\ (sorry, I should have left that bit un-blurred)